# How to use multiple \label across multiple \align* environments?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath, tags

For long calculations, I have two align* environments for two equations.

I have as an example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\label{Sum 1}1+2=3
1+2=3
1+2=3
1+2=3
1+2=3
1+2=3
1+2=3
\end{align*}
\\
\begin{align*}
\label{Sum 2}3+4=7
3+4=7
3+4=7
3+4=7
3+4=7
3+4=7
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile, it says there is an ams error from using "multiple label's" which means it somehow thinks both align* environments are on the same line even though they can't be. I want to use `align*` because I only want one label for an entire equation, I do not want to have to type `\nonumber` for every single line in a regular align environment.

Comment: use `align*` instead of `align`

Comment: When I use `\align*` it has no labels at all, I have to use `\intertext` which doesn't update with changes for cross referencing.

Comment: Please show us a short compilable code resulting in your issue. And please add a screenshot of your result to your question ...

Comment: it is `\begin{align*}` not `\align*` you could use `\tag` to add a label I can not guess what you mean by `\intertext` which works the same way with `align` and `align*`

Comment: When I say "align", it automatically implies I am using `\begin{align*}` because there is no other way it will compile. This shouldn't require a screen shot, it's a very simple situation, and given that and kurt's derailment attempt I feel like I'm being trolled. I am 100% certain there is an extremely simple solution here, I've seen it before, I just haven't used it in a long time.

Comment: sorry no we are suggesting that you make your question clear enough that people can help you, but if you would rather not, that is OK too.

Comment: My guess is I can use align*, and then use only one label and it will register the label only for that line, so I will try that.

Comment: I got it to work, but only for one equation, so I'm going to reformat the question entirely since it only lets me post once every 40 minutes for some reason.

Comment: The posted code has multiple errors (and would make no output) and so makes it hard to understand your question.

Comment: Well if I was a latex expert, I wouldn't be asking questions, which means your community is being elitist. If your community was more respectful then I would be open to sharing more information, but it has yet to earn that.

Comment: @user14554 your last comment is really strange. We don't need you to share any information. We don't _need_ to help you at all, we volunteer to do that in our free time. If you ask a question that is essentially "Something went wrong, how do I fix it?" then you will get comments asking to clarify the question, so people can help you. If you find that disrespectful, well no one can do much about that.

Answer (score 2):

Just spelling out @DavidCarlisle's comment. (Your code does not compile because there is no `\documentclass` and you have `\usepackage`s after `\begin{document}`. Nor does it make too much sense using `align` the way you do, so I *assume* you forgot to add multiple `\\`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
1+2&=3\\ 
1+2&=3\\
1+2&=3\\
1+2&=3\\
1+2&=3\\
1+2&=3\\
1+2&=3\label{Sum_1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
3+4&=7\\
3+4&=7\\
3+4&=7\\
3+4&=7\\
3+4&=7\\
3+4&=7\label{Sum_2}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
The equations under \eqref{Sum_1} are at least as illuminating as those under
\eqref{Sum_2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also have the article document class, but individual labels don't work. Why does adding tag do anything?

Comment: @user14554 `align*` produces equations without labels. To add a label you can use `\tag`. (IMHO the cleaner way would be to use `align` and `\notag` for all the lines that should not get a number, but this is a matter of taste.)